# Torch7 Lua, error loading module 'libpaths' (Linux)

Tags: linux, lua, torch

I am a new user to `TORCH LDT`.
I have trouble loading module '`libpaths`' (on `Ubuntu`). The **error log is**:

> Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: error
>   loading module 'libpaths' from file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so':
>     /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so: undefined symbol: lua_gettop    at
>   com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)  at
>   com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)   at
>   org.eclipse.koneki.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.koneki.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51DebugLauncher.main(JNLua51DebugLauncher.java:24)

What might be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is how to configure torch + eclipse:

**1) Configure the Lua interpreter with torch**:

Go to Windows -> Preference -> Lua -> interpreter:

- Interpreter Type   : Lua 5.2
- Interpreter executable : /opt/torch/install/bin/qlua    (-> this is
  required to use qt features)
- Interpreter name : Qt + Torch   Interpreter arguments : -lenv -e
  "io.stdout:setvbuf('no'); if os.getenv('DEBUG_MODE') then require
  'debugger' ; require 'debugger.plugins.ffi'end"
- LinkedExecution argument : Lua 5.2

**2)** Pick this interpreter as a default interpreter

**3)** Also Working with an external interpreter, require that  "LuaSocket" packet is installed, 
You will get a message error of "libsocket.so not found" when debugging if it is not installed

**To install LuaSocket, you may try** :

```
sudo luarocks install luasocket --only-server=http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks-scm
```

or

```
sudo luarocks install luasocket
```

or

```
luarocks install luasocket
```

Credits to [STRUB Floriab](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/torch7/wWwPjL9PgBU/MkloTN7QqT8J)

Comment: This link may help you to set [Lua Interpreter](https://wiki.eclipse.org/LDT/User_Area/User_Guides/User_Guide_1.0#Interpreters)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! However, I tried, and it doesn't help. I only change  the interpreter executable step:/opt/torch/ by changing to the location of torch folder. It still shows the same error log. Thx!

Comment: Have you kept the same path that you get by doing 'which qlua' in terminal, in interpreter executable, also did you install luasocket?, which ubuntu version are you using?